# Issue Google translator default language

Tags: php, google-translate

I am using the Google translator API, for transform my web sit contents, this language may differ for every time according to parameter.

```
<div style="float:right;font-weight:normal"><div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'hi'

  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script></div>
```

in this I have set default lang. as **hindi** or  **"hi"**, when page is loaded still content shows in english.

Although above on the page Google translator bar, it shows Hindi.

Please see the screen shot that will clear my point

[image]

Can any one please suggest me what is the problem in my code or what parameter I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
 new google.translate.TranslateElement({
pageLanguage: 'hi',
includedLanguages: 'en,hi',
multilanguagePage: true  
 }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?
```

cb=googleTranslateElementInit">

Try this ...this will work ...

Comment: NO! its not working... showing same result like I have attached.